# Guid generation in F# sequences

Tags: f#

I have the following code:

```
open System
open System.Linq

type Child = {
    id: Guid
    name: int
    parent: Guid
}

type Parent = {
    id: Guid
    name: int
    children: seq<Guid>
}

let makeChild name parentId =
    {
        Child.id = Guid.NewGuid()
        name = name
        parent = parentId
    }

let makeParent (group: IGrouping<int, int>) =
    let id = Guid.NewGuid()
    let children = group |> Seq.map (fun x -> makeChild x id)
    let ids = children |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.id)
    ({
        Parent.id = id
        name = group.Key
        children = ids
    }, children)

let makeAll (groups: seq<IGrouping<int, int>>) =
    let result = groups |> Seq.map (fun x -> makeParent x)
    let children = result |> Seq.map (fun x -> snd x) |> Seq.concat
    let parents = result |> Seq.map (fun x -> fst x)
    (parents, children)
```

(I accept `IGrouping<int, int>` instead of `seq<int * seq<int>>` because this code needs to interoperate with C#.)

However, when I run with the following:

```
let parents, children = makeAll(Enumerable.Range(0, 100).GroupBy(fun x -> x % 10))
```

then none of the children.[i].parent guids correlate with the parents.[j].children.[k] guids for i, j, k.

Why is this not the case? How can I get it to be so?

Answer (score 5):

Didn't test that, but it seems the problem is in the fact you enumerate the result seq twice, once in the `let children`, once in the `let parents` line. And since guid generation is side-effecting, you get two different results for each of the enumerations.

If you cache the seq in the `let result` line (or materialize it by turning it into an array or a list in the same line), you should get what you're looking for:

```
let result = groups |> Seq.map (fun x -> makeParent x) |> Seq.cache
```

The same in the `makeParent` function. The `ids` seq needs to be cached as well.

"Traps" like this are why I find it preferable to use concrete collection types rather than seqs on the boundaries of functions or interfaces. And if you're looking for laziness, you can make it explicit by using Lazy type.

Comment: Technically the `let children` line doesn't do any enumeration. However, the `ids` sequence, when enumerated, will regenerate all the children with different id's than those produced when the `children` sequence is enumerated. You're right on about the fix.

Comment: @JoelMueller: Right, I focused on the `makeAll` code, and you're talking about `makeParent` code. Indeed that needs to be cached as well.